# How to properly identify legacy AMD (ATI) IGP graphics unit and install drivers for it?

Tags: drivers, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst

I have this OEM board made by ASUS. The model number is M2R-FVM. I have done a clean install of Windows Vista and I need to install proper drivers for it. I'm not sure what drivers to get.

If I open Device Manager it says RADEON XPRESS 200 Series.

[image: a]

If I go to AMD website, download and run the AMD Driver Autodetect tool it says Radeon Xpress 1150.

[image: b]
[image: c]
[image: d]

This contradicts the previous statement. There is an option to download either Xpress 1150 drivers or Xpress 200 drivers right on the driver download page. But which one is it? Is it Xpress 1150 or Xpress 200?

[image: e]

There's also the option "Not Sure". This brings up the "how to identify the model of an AMD graphics card" article. Ironically, one of the methods described is to check with the Device Manager.

[image: f]
[image: g]
[image: h]

So how can I be sure I'm getting the correct device drivers then?

**Addendum**

If it's of any help, the motherboard manual I found on the web lists RS485 as south bridge and SB600 as north bridge. Does that mean I need the chipset drivers rather than graphics drivers? I'm not sure whether or not the graphics chip is actually part of the chipset?... I'm confused. What's the name of the "chip set" then if RS485 is the north bridge and SB600 is the south bridge?

Note! This is not a PCI-Express graphics card, it's part of the motherboard design. Apparently it's also known as IGP (integrated graphics processor). That's how it's listed on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ATI_Graphics_Processing_Units#Radeon_R300_Series) anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try to look for ati catalyst. Its ati software that should detect and install the right graphic drivers.

Comment: Do you mean AMD Catalyst or ATI Catalyst (pre-AMD)? If ATI Catalyst, then what version do you suggest? Yes, just grabbing the latest AMD Catalyst might work for recent generation Radeon graphics adapters. But it probably won't work if you are stuck with a "legacy" product and AMD has dropped the support for it in the latest Catalyst software. Even more so if you are stuck with "OEM" and "IGP" products. It's a different story if you use a recent Radeon PCI-Express graphics card. Even my old HD2400 works with the latest AMD Catalyst software, still supported. Your answer is only half the truth.

Comment: Ok, didnt knew that cause im using most of the time nvida stuff but i had also some pcs with ati grapic cards. If you want to identify the right grapics card look into the device manager and look for the vendor and device id. That should give you a clear hint what card you have.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you want to use the driver that Asus provides.  If you download it from the Asus website, then it is guaranteed to work.

Why does it show up as two different models?  Well, there could be a variety of reasons.  Most likely, the Radeon 200 is based on the 1150, but modified to Asus' specifications.

In the end, you can try all the drivers.  Best case, you have a newer driver with more options.  Worst case, you have to uninstall the driver.

Comment: This is an OEM board. It's made by ASUS alright, but it's not a retail product. So it's not listed anywhere on ASUS website. Unfortunately, that's a no go. But I've found a reference to it at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ATI_Graphics_Processing_Units#Radeon_R300_Series). It's listed under "IGP". Apparently this is not R200, but R300. It went by the name "Xpress 1150" as well as "Xpress 200". There are no further details, nor any source reference. It was available with both FSB and HT bus depending on platform (mine is AMD, so HT).

Comment: It says on Wikipedia that the code name was "RS485". That's the north bridge, right? So does that mean that IGP is integral part of the north bridge? I actually had the suggested Xpress 1150 driver (10-2_legacy_vista32-64_dd_ccc.exe) installed once before, but after doing so the PC started BSOD-ing at random while in Windows. I figured it might be driver related. So I've done a clean install of Windows, and it seems to be OK right now on generic Microsoft drivers.

Comment: But this could also indicate a bigger problem, because I started seeing BSODs (though not so often) before that, and the fan on the Nvidia Geforce 8500 GT died and I was getting no video signal and there was a BIOS beep code. Once I pulled out the Geforce the PC started booting again. So I started using the built-in Radeon IGP as a temporary solution. And it worked for a while, but I started having problems shutting it down where on shut down it would close Windows and then show some graphical jitter right before shutting down, and then just reboot. It wouldn't shut down normally.

Comment: I then started installing different drivers for the IGP. I first installed the drivers that came with the PC on a drivers CD. It installed Catalyst 7.2 and some chipset drivers I think, LAN and Audio drivers for Realtek. I then had the suggested legacy drivers installed (Catalyst 10.2) from AMD website over that. Perhaps that was a mistake...

Comment: I won't bore you with all my troubles. Long story short: I just want to make sure I have identified the graphics chip correctly and that I am installing the correct drivers. :) I guess I'll just have to try them out one by one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The name of it in the device manager should be considered as authoritative. The auto-detection tool may have misidentified the device.